# How to delete my question?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

I want to delete [my question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253947/).

But i am not able to delete it? How to do that?

Comment: You cannot delete that particular question because it has an upvoted answer. You have solicited work from the community and received it; deleting the question would also delete the answers written to help you, which is not fair to the people that wrote them.

Comment: Note, however, that there's no real need to delete questions just because they're closed; closed questions can still be valuable markers either to other questions or as indicators of what is and is not on-topic here. If a closed question should really be deleted, [the system will delete it automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006) without needing intervention.

Comment: For clarity, the linked question was deleted (due to its negative score) when its owner account was removed, as per point 11 in https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/.

Answer (score 4):

If a "delete" link appears below the question, at the left just under the tags, then click that.

> [image]

If you don't see that link, it means that something about the question or one of its answers makes it worth keeping. There are [various reasons this can happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/56541).